# Circular References Example

Tags: java

I have a group: a parent object and a child object. The objects may be attached to each other post-instantiation. I would like to have a circular reference between these objects, but maintain re-usability by *not* having a dependency.

For instance: the parent is `Firewall` and the child is `Route`. I would like to attach the `Route` to the `Firewall` and vice versa. On the `Route` I will call `this.getParent()` and be provided with `Firewall`.

How can I accomplish this?

OK, So i'm adding some code as an example:

```
public class Firewall_Record extends DefaultDevice implements Comparable, Serializable { 
private Object parent;

public void addRoute(Route r){
r.setParent(this);
}

public void setparent(Object o){...}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Firewall_Record)) {
        return false;
    }

    Firewall_Record rhs = (Firewall_Record) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().
            append(this.parent, rhs.parent).
            isEquals();
}

}


public class Route_Record implements Comparable, Serializable { 
private Object parent;

public void setparent(Object o){...}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Firewall_Record)) {
        return false;
    }

    Firewall_Record rhs = (Firewall_Record) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().
            append(this.parent, rhs.parent).
            isEquals();
}

}
```

I don't want to go back and modify all the classes to extend to some base class that implements Serializable if I can avoid it.

I created this Interface that would solve my problem of being able to set a generic Parent Object and not creating dependencies. I'm struggling to see a way to apply it though.

```
public interface ParentInterface<T> {

   T getParent();

   void setParent(T t);

}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that you require a circular dependency?  (By the way, this isn't all that hard to accomplish; what have you done to get this to work and where have you stumbled?)

Comment: I fthe modell has a circular task, then just let it circular.

Comment: If Firewall must reference Route, then it must depend on the Route.  If Route must reference Firewall, then it must depend on Firewall.  You can change the coupling, but never remove it.

Comment: @DwB - Two objects can reference each other without depending on each other's classes.

Comment: This will take some explaining. Firewall and Route may both have Parents. The problem i'm having is that I need to compare firewalls to firewalls and routes to routes in the ".equals". One of the values i need to compare is  the field "parent". My classes (Firewall and Route) implement Serializable because I save them locally. Class Object does not implement Serializable, so i can't just have a generic field called "Object parent;" in both Firewall and Route.

Comment: In order to have a reference to an object of type Firewall, the class must import the class Firewall.  This means that if the Firewall class is not available at compile or (more importantly) runtime, an error (or exception) will happen.  This is a dependancy.

Comment: Do `Firewall` and `Route` currently inherit from anything? I see why there are downvotes.. No code, and "*How can I accomplish this?*" seems to refer to "*How can I create a getter and setter for `Firewall` and `Route`*"? - but you are actually asking something completely different from your comment.

Comment: The best you can do is create some common base class for Firewall and Route that will support equals and serialization and depend on that class.

Answer (score 2):

You have some confusion about what constitutes a 'dependency'. To accomplish what you want is very simple:

```
class Parent {
  Child child;
  public void setChild(Child c) { this.child = c; }
  public Child getChild() { return this.child; }
}

class Child {
  Parent parent;
  public void setParent(Parent p) { this.parent = p; }
  public Parent getParent() { return this.parent; }
}
```

In each case, the object can hold a *reference* to another object. This does not create a *dependency*. A dependency would look more like this:

```
class A extends B {
  ...
}

class B extends A {
  ...
}
```

In this case, each class is defined by the other class. Neither can be constructed first because it requires knowledge of the other, and thus is a circular dependency. This is explicitly disallowed in Java.

Now, in regards to your `equals()` case, it is pretty unclear what you're attempting. Witness:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //These clauses make sense
    if (obj == null) { return false; }
    if (obj == this) { return true; }
    if (!(obj instanceof Firewall_Record)) { return false; }

    Firewall_Record rhs = (Firewall_Record) obj;

    //This will handle null values.
    return Objects.equals(this.parent, rhs.parent)
}
```

This comes from the `import java.util.Objects;` library. It will handle having null values passed to it.

Comment: The problem I have is that "Parent" appears in the .equals. If the class ends up having no parent there is a null pointer. If I do "Parent parent=new Parent()" I have a stack over flow as both classes point to each other.

Comment: You should post the code where you try and do this, because it's unclear how you're doing it in a way where you are causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

create a default serializable object - this `MyObject` would replace wherever you plan on using `Object`.

```
class MyObject implements Serializable
{
    //... default code
}
```

have `parent` be a field of type `MyObject` - and have `Firewall` and `Route` extend `MyObject`.

---

Alternatively, you seem to want to be able to attach to *any Serializable Object* rather than just certain ones that would extend a custom class.

Instead of parent being `MyObject`, have this:

```
class Firewall //extends whatever
{
    Serializable parent;
}

class Router // extends whatever
{
    Serializable parent;
}
```

I'm not sure what you expect to be able to accomplish with the attached `Objects` - I think the only thing you could do is serialize and deserialize them - if you want further interactions with them, at some point you'd have to start expecting certain classes or method annotations.

---

In reference to your new question - you need to `implement` your interface and provide the two methods you have defined into the class.

Comment: Thought about doing this, but then you are left with the same problem. "parent" is still defined as "Object parent;" in "MyObject" which is not serializable.

Comment: `MyObject` *is* the parent - why would it hold an `Object`?

Comment: If "MyObject" contains a field called parent, what class is parent going to be?

Comment: `Firewall` and `Route` contain a `MyObject` called "parent", while `MyObject` only has default serialization code and nothing else. It is a replacer for `Object`, but can be serialized.

Comment: The problem then becomes that setting a MyObject requires the object being set to extend MyObject correct?

Comment: Yes. You currently extend `DefaultDevice`, and that could extend `MyObject`, or - however up the chain you need to go where it finally extends into `Object`, extend `MyObject` instead. (*note that no "extends" means it extends `Object`*)

Comment: I'm sorry, Route does not extend DefaultDevice.

Comment: @JamieSnipes That doesn't matter.. you would have it extend `MyObject` directly then instead of `Object`. So long as both Firewall and Route both *eventually* extend `MyObject`.

Comment: This solution requires every Object that Firewall attaches to in the future to be an extension of MyObject.

Comment: @JamieSnipes Why is that a problem?

Comment: If that is the way it has to absolutely be done, i'm ok with it.But it would limit the types of Objects I could attach to in the future. Say another developer comes up with a class "Rack" and I want to attach to that. I will not be able to.

Comment: @JamieSnipes I have proposed an alternative, but all you'd really be able to do with the `parent` is serialize or deserialize it. If you want further interactions you have to eventually *expect* some class or methods you can do something with. If this still is a problem - let me know, but note that the other Developer could just include your `jar` and have his `Rack extend MyObject`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot seeing your solution. I think it will work. I think I will be able to use instanceof to determine the Object type later, correct?

Comment: @JamieSnipes That is correct, but if another Developer wants to attach his `Object` you'll have to include the `instanceof` his `Object` - which might not be a problem if the other developer needs to handle the `instanceof`'ing

Comment: @JamieSnipes I just realized you are probably looking from the perspective of including *their* library into *your* project - rather than them including *your* library into *their* project. So nevermind me ><, but that is correct.